# Vue - Bind value of object to a checkbox value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to put the value of every item into array `selectedParks`. The problem is, the value is always set to string "item", and not the value of the actual item (it's a Park Object).

Code:

```
<ul class="list-group no-bullets">
    <li class="list-group-item" v-for="item in parks">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="item" v-model="selectedParks"/> {{item.name}}</label>
    </li>
</ul>
<span>Checked: {{selectedParks}}</span>
```

I know that the actual `item` is bound correctly, because `{{item.name}}` shows the correct value.

Docs (multiple checkboxes bound to the same array): https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: Could you describe the `Park Object` data structure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That because `value` is being assessed as a string, you need to use v-bind to set it as an object:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="item" v-model="selectedParks"/>
```

or the colon shorthand:

```
<input type="checkbox" :value="item" v-model="selectedParks"/>
```

Comment: If you look closely, the `item` is an object. I think you need something like: `:value="item.selected"`

Comment: @Alfa, looks like he wants to bind the entire object to me, which is fine: https://jsfiddle.net/7hxL3tcs/

Comment: @alfa why bind a property of an object when you can bind the whole object?

Comment: @Bert `park` object has `name` property. I think it would not work if you bind the whole object.

Comment: Aaah, I see, we have different approach. Here's mine https://jsfiddle.net/ob0ohfL6/

Comment: @Alfa If `value` is bound to `item`, then, when the checkbox is checked, the entire `park` object represented by `item` will be pushed in the array. Its much more common to want the entire object than just a property of it.

Comment: @Green_qaue It looks fine to me, here's a JSFiddle for you to take a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/ac9areeo/